# Selecionando valores específicos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-select

Primeiramente obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Não manjo muito de SQL, estou com uma dúvida de como realizar um select.

Tenho algumas tabelas, segue essas como exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como dou um select para saber as pessoas que estão cadastradas, exibindo sua cidade, mas sem duplicar o cadastro 
Gustavo ali visitou duas cidades mas quero que ele apareça 1 vez apenas no cadastro. 
Quando eu abrir o formulário do cadastro dele, vai aparecer as cidades que ele visitou, com esse exemplo consigo realizar o que quero, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois juntos, acredito que não tenha jeito, mas você pode fazer um de cada vez:

1- Buscar as Pessoas com as Cidades delas

```
select Pessoa.id, Pessoa.nome, Cidade.id, Cidade.nome, Cidade.UF from Pessoa inner join Cidade on Pessoa.cidade_id = Cidade.id
```

2- Depois onde você for mostrar as cidades que cada pessoa visitou você faz:

```
select Cidade.id, Cidade.nome, Cidade.UF where Cidade.id in (select CidadesVisitadas.cidade_id where CidadesVisitadas.pessoa_id = 1)
```

Onde coloquei "1", você colocaria algum "Pessoa.id" trazido do primeiro select.

Comment: A sim é uma possibilidade, obrigadoajudou mt